# Is 2-oxobicyclo[2.2.1]heptan-1-ide resonance stabilized?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, resonance

Is the following compound resonance stabilized?

[image: 2-oxobicyclo[2.2.1]heptan-1-ide]

I think its not resonance stabilized because the p-orbital of carbanion and pure p-orbital of carbonyl carbon are not in same plane. So they can't overlap. (Pure means that the p-orbital is not a part of the $\ce{sp^2}$ orbital. One p-orbital of carbonyl carbon is pure).
Am I correct?

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: Let’s start by saying that the anion is not centred in an $\ce{sp^2}$ orbital but in an $\ce{sp^3}$ one. But yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think, in contrast to cyclohexanone, a resonance stabilization by

[image]

is less likely to happen as you already start with a bi-cyclic compound where the cycles involved are small to moderate. The then *additional* strain introduced by a (partial) double bond at the bridge-head carbon atom would destabilize the molecule too much.  I extrapolate here from [Bredt's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bredt's_rule).

Answer (score 11):

The reason for this is, as Buttonwood suggested, the strain induced by the bicyclic norbonyl system. I already hinted in the comments that the anion is in a $\ce{sp^3}$ type orbital. What makes it impossible is that that orbital is almost orthogonal to the carbonyl’s $\unicode[Times]{x3C0}$-bond. I attempted to draw two pictures below, one being the complete, the second a Newman projection along the anion-carbonyl carbon bond. The exact angles might be different ones, but these visualisations can serve as a starting point.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

No,it's not resonance stablised, the reason is , the bridge head carbon with negative charge is sp3 hybridised and has tetrahedral geometry but for overlapping with parallel orbitals of carbonyl  needs parallel p orbital  and it's not possible due to its tetrahedral geometry.